# How to get reimbursement of the wrong taxes collected by IRS?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, reimbursement

I was working as an intern with F1 visa status at a company but that company's HR didn't know that I shouldn't be charged for medicare & SSN tax, so they put me in that tax status and now I have graduated though in F1-OPT and employed in new company. But since I was put in that tax status the IRS kept collecting the SSN & Medicare taxes from me.

So how do I tell IRS that I shouldn't have been charged for it and get my money back?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but to clarify a little, *bracket* is not the correct word here - that refers to income ranges that correspond to particular tax rates.  Maybe the word you want is *status*?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36813/improper-withholding-of-fica-from-student-getting-a-refund Also, why the previous employer's decisions are affecting the current? For the current employer - go to their payroll and tell them.